Origins of the diagrams in Rashi, Rashbam or Tosefos
In Bava Basra 62 there are some diagrams/illustrations in the commentaries Rashbam and Tosefos, related to the topic of borders of fields, as well as in many other places in the Talmud.
My question is, were these diagrams in the original manuscripts written by the authors or were they added later?
I did some research and found these manuscripts on Sefaria.

Bomberg (Venice) Pressing (1523 CE) - this one seems to have space for the diagrams, but they were either erased or never added, the one that is there seems to be hand drawn
Munich Manuscript 95 (1342 CE) - I dont see any diagrams, but I am not sure if the commentary is Rashbam and if the diagrams may be on a different page
The Vilna page linked at the start of the question does have the diagrams in a less graphically pleasing format then the modern Oz Vehadar I saw them in, so there is definitely upgrades done by each publisher

Also, if the commentator wrote "כזה" is that an indication that he drew a diagram in the original manuscript"
If anyone can point to any research or more info on this subject I would appreciate it.

I don't think there's one comprehensive resource here. Any individual diagram can be traced back through various versions over the years.

I understand there will be various versions but was the first version added by the commentator, or later on.
I added a question about when it says "כזה" which would seem to indicate that it was added as it was being written

Manuscripts used to be handwritten (literal definition of manuscripts). So one could draw images. My guess is the images began to be left out after the invention of printing, where they did not have letter blocks for the drawings. Then people decided to include them again, but the originals had been lost.
